# Randomly rotate image in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm new to Imagemagick. I need to rotate this pattern

[image: original image]

for some random angle in degrees.  What I can do at my best is:

```
convert -rotate -15 -background none originfile.png savefile.png
```

which produces this:

[image: rotated image]

I have a problem:

I need to have a random rotation angle in the range from -30 to 30. But right now, I can only choose the rotation angle manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need **ImageMagick** v7 or better for this:

```
magick pattern.png -background none -rotate "%[fx:-30+60*rand()]" result.png
```

That rotates by -30 + 60 x random number on [0,1], i.e. -30 to +30.

[image: result]

---

If you don't have version 7, you can generate the random number in `bash`:

```
convert pattern.png -background none -rotate "$((RANDOM%60-30))" result.png
```

Or, if you want to see/check the value first, you can do it over 2 lines:

```
((r=(RANDOM%60)-30))
convert pattern.png -background none -rotate "$r" result.png
```

---

If you happen to be on Windows, you can generate a random number between -30 and +30 like this, I think:

```
set /a number=-30 + %random% %% 60
convert pattern.png -background none -rotate %number% result.png
```

Answer (score 2):

With ImageMagick v6 you can get a random rotation between -30 and 30 degrees by using "+distort" in a command like this...

```
convert originfile.png -background none \
   -virtual-pixel none +distort SRT "%[fx:-60*random()+30]" savefile.png
```

For IM v7 you should use "magick" instead of "convert".

Answer (score 1):

One more option is to combine Mark Setchell and GeeMack commands for ImageMagick 6 as:

```
angle=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:-60*random()+30]" info:)
convert pattern.png -background none -rotate $angle result.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a random function and feed it to your command as a variable. If you are using V7 you might be able to do it in the command.